# Does snowflake (privatelink) support the custom domain?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to access a private Snowflake link on our domain.
Does snowflake support this?

custom domaub -> *.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com -> (privatelink)vpce domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's currently not possible to use custom domain URLs rather than the one provided by Snowflake.